# create multi file docx from a template within hyperlink in python

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to create a python program that starts from a file.docx and a file.csv creates multiple .docx files.
The problem is that the original file contains hyperlinks that are lost in the creation of new files

this is my python program

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

import csv
import os


f = open('file.csv')
nometofind = '[nome]'
cognometofind = '[cognome]'
reader = csv.reader(f)
next(reader)
for row in reader:

    cognome=row[0]
    nome=row[1]

    nometoreplace = nome
    cognometoreplace = cognome

    document = Document('OriginalFile.docx')
    
    for par in document.paragraphs:
        par.text = par.text.replace(nometofind, nometoreplace)
        par.text = par.text.replace(cognometofind, cognometoreplace)

    document.save(nome+cognome+'.docx')

f.close()
```

and this is an example of may original docx

> [nome][cognome] email [example@example.com](http://example@example.com)

the output files are like these

> output file 1->  john smith email
>
> output file 2->  mario rossi email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, this is how to get a link inside DOCX file with "**python-docx**" library

```
    from docx import Document
    from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

    document = Document('nameFile.docx')
    rels = document.part.rels

    def leggiLink(rels):
        for rel in rels:
            if rels[rel].reltype == RT.HYPERLINK:
                yield rels[rel]._target
    print('print link inside file: nameFile.docx')

    for i in leggiLink(rels):
        print(i)
```